# Select only one specific value from tables

Tags: sql, select, join

I have 3 tables:

- `Duties`
- `Activities`
- `Activity Types`

One duty has one or more activities, and one activity has multiple activity types.

For example I have 2 duties:

1. Duty 1 has 2 activities. Activity 1 with activity type "TYPE1", and activity 2 with activity type "TYPE2".
2. Duty 2 has 2 activities and both activities have activity types "TYPE2".

I want my select statement to retrieve all the duties with "TYPE2", but if a duty has activities with activity types "TYPE1", "TYPE2" or any other type it should not select them. I.e. select only duties where all activities have activity type "TYPE2".

Here is my current query:

```
select columns from duties d
join activity a on d.duty_id = a.id
join activity_type t on t.id = a.act_id and activity_type = 'TYPE2'
```

Comment: Please review the answers. If one answer was sufficient, please don't forget to mark your question as answered by checking the checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can afford it with a subquery, this is the readable way: *"all duties with a Type2 activity that no has other type activities"*:

```
select distinct columns 
from duties d
join activity a2 on d.duty_id = a2.id
join activity_type t2 on t2.id = a2.act_id and activity_type = 'TYPE2'
where d.duty_id not in
( select duty_id.id from duties d
  join activity a on d.duty_id = a.id
  join activity_type t on t.id = a.act_id and activity_type <> 'TYPE2' 
)
```

Notice than this kind of query have **not high performance** due subquery is executed for each main query row.

Without subqueries in standard sql:

```
select columns 
from 
  (
    select columns (including duty_id )
    from duties d
    join activity a on d.duty_id = a.id
    join activity_type t on t.id = a.act_id and activity_type = 'TYPE2'
  ) as yesT2
left outer join
  (
    select distinct d.duty_id 
    from duties d
    join activity a on d.duty_id = a.id
    join activity_type t on t.id = a.act_id and activity_type <> 'TYPE2'
  ) as yesT1
on 
  yesT2.duty_id = yesT1.duty_id
where
  yesT1.duty_id is Null
```

May be improved in readability iy our database brand supports CTE.

Comment: this is exactly what i did and it worked but i was told not to use subqueryes :(

Comment: @user3436814, ok, posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
select duty_name from duty
except
select duty_name from duties d
join activity a on d.duty_id = a.id
join activity_type t on t.id = a.act_id and activity_type <> 'TYPE2'
```

This will exclude any activity that has other activity type